# Using a child process to keep a SSH pseudo-tty-less connection open in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ssh, expect

I want to create a `Ruby` script which opens a SSH pseudo-tty-less connection, and keeps it open.

I also want to send it the password with help of e.g. `expect`.

I have tried this: (I have removed servername, password and username)

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require "pty"
require "expect"

username = 'USERNAME'
server   = 'SERVERNAME'
password = 'PASSWORD'

r_f, w_f, pid = PTY.spawn("ssh -T -l #{username} #{server}")

w_f.sync = true

r_f.expect(/.*asswor.*/, 600) do |output|
  w_f.puts password
  puts "Sending password"
end

# If we are logged on, we get a message with "Hello, username"
r_f.expect(/.*ello.*/) do
  puts "You are now logged on."
end
```

However, this seems to close the connection after it has received confirmation that it is connected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your process must stay alive. If your process dies, the child processes are killed and the pty is destroyed. You can make your process sleep forever:

```
sleep
```

Comment: Doh! It was really that simple.